# Dynatree how to send data back to the server on tree modifications

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, dynatree, jquery-dynatree

I am using Dynatree with ASP.NET and MVC4, I was able to Initialize Tree with the Data from Server end.

My question is how i can send data back to server on certain tree modifications. (For example Edit Node, Cut Copy Paste, Drag drop etc.)

Is there any working example to look at?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to do an `Ajax` call to the server and pass relevant data from the corresponding `dynatree` event handler. For example, for drag'n'drop, you would do smth like:

```
$("#tree").dynatree({
    dnd: {
        onDrop: function(node, sourceNode, hitMode, ui, draggable) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: [url],
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                data: JSON.stringify(node.data),
                success: function (arg) {
                    alert(JSON.stringify(arg));
                },
                error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                    alert(JSON.stringify(xhr.responseText));
                }
        }
    }
});
```